# Dynamically setting row onclick event in jquery DataTable initialization

Tags: datatables, asp.net-ajax

I'm loading data into a table using ajax that calls my controller function. When a new page is selected or a column is sorted, I reload the data by using ajax to that same original controller function. This is so that I don't load all of the items right away, only when needed. I want to make each row have an onclick javascript function where I can get the column information from that row that was clicked. Any ideas? The controller function just gets my data based on what result range the user wants to see and what sorted order.

My only javascript code is the following:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var oTable;
        oTable = $('#tblItemModel').DataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "paginate": true,
            "ajaxSource": "/Finance/ItemListAjax",
            "processing": true,
            "serverMethod": "GET",
            "displayLength": 50
        });
    })
</script>
```

My html is the following:

```
<table class="table table-striped at-table" id="tblItemModel">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Id
                </th>
                <th>
                     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ListPrice)
                </th>
                <th>
                      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiscountPrice)
                </th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody class="mousechange"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually work in this way to get data when you click in a row...

in dataTable()

```
    $('#tblItemModel tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

       var pos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
       var row = oTable.fnGetData(pos);//row = It contains all the data in that row

    });
```

for DataTable()

```
    $('#tblItemModel tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

       var pos = oTable.row(this).index();
       var row = oTable.row(pos).data();//row = It contains all the data in that row

    });
```

Comment: That will not work since `oTable` in the question is an instance of `DataTable`. It would work if  `oTable` was an instance of `dataTable` instead. Replace `oTable` with `$('#tblItemModel').dataTable()` to correct this. Or use [1.10.x API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/) instead.

Comment: Great! That did the trick. I was making some progress with "fnDrawCallback": function () { } in the initialization of the table, but yours is simpler.